# .htaccess entire wordpress site except one page

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, passwords

Hi I would like to password protect my entire Wordpress site using .htaccess. All pages except one page which would be viewable to the public. I know there are other methods out there built into wordpress but I would like to have all pages except the one protected using the .htaccess method.

How do I make that one page viewable without a password?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in your .htaccess file.

```
#require a password for the whole site.
AuthName "Authorization Required"
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile /path/to/.htpasswd
require valid-user
#allow just this page unprotected
<Files "somepage\.html">
  allow from all
  satisfy any
</Files>
```

https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/BypassAuthenticationOrAuthorizationRequirements